# Is there way to make extensions polymorphic?

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, polymorphism, extension-methods

I have following java classes I can't change

```
interface Parent...
class Child1Class implements Parent...
class Child2Class implements Parent...
class GrandChild1Class extends Child1Class ...
...
```

Now I write Kotlin application.

I want to add some functionality to all the hierarchy.

```
fun Parent.foo(){ println("Parent.foo")
```

but I want to have special behaviour for `GrandChild1Class`

```
fun GrandChild1Class.foo(){ println("GrandChild1Class.foo")
```

But if I write:

```
val grandChild1: Parent = GrandChild1Class()
grandChild1.foo()
```

I see `Parent.foo` because of reference type

But I expected to see `GrandChild1Class.foo`

Is there way to achieve polymorphic behavior for such kinda things ?

Comment: No. In bytecode, the extension method becomes a static method, and the receiver becomes the first parameter. There is no way to make this polymorphic because JVM doesn't support it.

Comment: @Sweeper is there any other trick to have such a behaviour ?

Comment: How about just check the type of `this` with `is`? `when(this) { is A -> ... is B -> ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Kotlin implements extension functions as static Java methods, with the receiver of the extension function being the first parameter of the Java method.

```kotlin
fun String.foo() { }
```

becomes

```java
public static void foo(String $this$foo) { }
```

Of course, static methods are *statically* dispatched, so there is no polymorphism.

The simple workaround is to just check the type with a `when`.

```kotlin
fun Parent.foo() = when(this) {
    is GrandChild1Class -> println("GrandChild1Class.foo")
    // other cases...
    // remember to put "more specific" cases first!
    else -> println("Parent.foo")
```

---

The only instructions in the JVM that can dynamically dispatch methods are `invokeinferface`, `invokevirtual`, and `invokedynamic`. The first two both require the method to be declared in the class/interface of the instance the method is called, which extension methods cannot do. i.e. declaring `fun String.foo()` in Kotlin can't possibly add a `foo` method to `java.lang.String`.

The Kotlin compiler can in theory use `invokedynamic`. It would find all the applicable extension methods, do some overload resolution, and return a `CallSite` corresponding to a particular extension method it found. In practice, this would require a lot of designing to figure out what the exact behaviours should be, as well as big changes to the compiler, and breaking source-compatibility.